# how to implement csplit into a makefile?

Tags: unix, makefile

How do I implement specifically A & B into the following makefile. : The programmers of this project have opted to package some of their code in a “module” called chomp.adt, from which the related files cookie.h and cookie.cpp files can be generated.
The steps necessary to produce this program are:

A. Run the command

```
    csplit chomp.adt "/Split Here/"
```

and copy the resulting file xx00 to cookie.h.

B. Run the command

```
csplit chomp.adt "/Split Here/"
```

and copy the resulting file xx01 to cookie.cpp.

C. Compile cookie.cpp to produce cookie.o.

D. Compile mainProg.cpp to produce mainProg.o.

E. Link the .o files to produce an executable program named playChomp

How can I write a makefile that will carry out ALL these steps? I understand how to implement C-E I believe, its mostly A and B where I am confused how to make a rule of this. When I attempted I wrote A and B as-

```
cookie.h: csplit chomp.adt
         cp xx00 cookie.h
cookie.cpp: csplit chomp.adt
         cp xx01 cookie.cpp
```

I received the error, "no rule to make target csplit needed by cookie.cpp".

Comment: I've improved the layout of the code snippets, but I'm not sure I've got the `cookie.h` and `cookie.cpp` rules laid out the same as you did.  As shown, they'd produce the error message you show.  Please check.  Note that you don't normally depend on the command, and you do need to execute the command (including the context on which it is to split).

Comment: Also, if you use numbers (instead of letters) to identify the items in the list, you can get nicely indented items. However, instead of indenting code by just 4 spaces, you need to use 8 spaces inside the list.

Answer (score 3):

A simple makefile rule has the syntax:

```
<target> : <prerequisites>
        <recipe>
```

where the target is the output file to be built, the prerequisites are the input files used to build the target, and the recipe is the process by which the input files are turned into output files.

The command `csplit ...` is part of the *recipe*.  It should not be listed as a prerequisite.

So your rule should look something like:

```
cookie.h: chomp.adt
        csplit $< "/Split Here/"
        cp xx00 $@

cookie.cpp: chomp.adt
        csplit $< "/Split Here/"
        cp xx01 $@
```

You can read about `$<` and `$@` here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html
It's not strictly necessary to use them.

However, the above rules are not ideal because you're running the csplit command twice when you don't need to.  And if you try to run make with parallel builds enabled (`make -jN`) it may fail because both will run at the same time and overwrite the output files.

How you can do better depends on which version of GNU make you have.  If you have GNU make 4.3, you can use:

```
cookie.h cookie.cpp &: chomp.adt
        csplit $< "/Split Here/"
        cp xx00 cookie.h
        cp xx01 cookie.cpp
```

This is a grouped target which you can read about here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html#index-grouped-targets

If you have an older version, you can play a trick enabled by the fact that the targets and prerequisite all start with the same prefix (the letter `c`); it would look like this:

```
%ookie.h %ookie.cpp : %homp.adt
        csplit $< "/Split Here/"
        cp xx00 cookie.h
        cp xx01 cookie.cpp
```

This is a pattern rule, which you can read about here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html

Comment: You could also use: `cookie.h cookie.cpp: chomp.adt` with the recipe you give.  Since the targets are evaluated one at a time in a non-parallel build, when it builds `cookie.h`, it also builds `cookie.cpp` and won't need to do it again.  Parallel building runs into trouble as you said.  The rule shown doesn't depend on the coincidence that the file names all start with the letter c — it would work with `cookie.h`, `biscuit.cpp` and `datafile.adt`, for example.

Comment: Yes but it would break with parallel builds.  So I don't consider it much of an improvement over the first example.  Avoiding the extra csplit is something but I doubt the time it takes is measurable.

Comment: I don't do that many parallel builds, so it wouldn't matter much to me, but I did note that it has a problem with parallel builds.  OTOH, it works with older versions of `make`, GNU and non-GNU.  If it weren't for the non-comment notation used for the split marker, the split wouldn't be necessary, unless `mainProg.cpp` includes `cookie.h`.  Of course, there's a moderate probability that the code in `mainProg.cpp` does include `cookie.h`, but it isn't stated.  It would be better to have whatever generates `chomp.adt` generate the separate `cookie.h` and `cookie.cpp` files, too.

Comment: The 'grouped targets' information is interesting — thank you for that.